# How to Read FTDI Response Buffer C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, windows-ce, ftdi

I am developing a Windows CE application and currently using a Forms Application to test Reading and Writing by sending the data via USB connection.I am using FTDID2xx DLL to test my application but am unable to get the correct response despite being able to write successfully to the device.Below is my sample Write and Read function.Kindly advise how i can be able to properly read the response send back via Cable.

Below is my Write Function

```
        string message = "";
        UInt32 dwRet = 0;
        FT_STATUS ftStatus = FT_STATUS.FT_OTHER_ERROR;
        int i;
        const int bytesize = 1024 * 1024;

        byte[] cBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        i = cBuf.Length;

        fixed (byte* pBuf = cBuf)
        {
            ftStatus = FT_Write(m_hPort, pBuf, (uint)(i + 1), ref dwRet);
        }
        if (ftStatus != FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
        {

            message = "Failed To Write " + Convert.ToString(ftStatus);
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Written" + " " + ftStatus.ToString() + " " + ftStatus;
            fixed (byte* pBuf = cBuf)
            {
                ftStatus = FT_Read(m_hPort, pBuf, (uint)(i + 1), ref dwRet);
            }
        }
```

**Below is my Updated Read Version**

```
       byte[] cBuf = new byte[528];

        int counter = 0;
        UInt32 dwRet = 0;

        UInt32 length = 528;
        while (dwRet == 0)
        {

            FT_STATUS ftStatus;

            fixed (byte* pBuf = cBuf)
            {
                ftStatus = FT_Read(m_hPort, pBuf, length, ref dwRet);

            }             


            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
```

Comment: Your read function doesn't read.  Your write function does read.  What is your question?  What are you seeing happen and what were you wanting to happen?

Comment: Hi @BenVoigt   .What i am intending to do is to get the response that has been returned by my device.I am sending data to my terminal device which should send the response back.I can see the cable "lights" up showing a response has been returned.That response which has been returned is the one i am intending to read back.

Comment: `FT_Read` at the bottom of your first code snippet (the one you called "Write") should be putting data into `cBuf`.  The amount of data would be recorded in `dwRet`.  What are you getting?  You may have to change your read timeouts.

Comment: Hi @BenVoigt Sorry i have left the workstation device and i will test tomorrow again since the code is running physically on that device.However,if i can ask for maybe a small clarification.When i write to my terminal,I am technically supposed to wait till the data has been written back to the cable so that i can read the response.During this time of waiting for response.should i be on an endless loop while calling my read function above? .I appreciate much your response

Comment: Hi @BenVoigt,So i have tested again and i am receiving 0 bytes on my read function.Below is my read function.

Comment: I refer you back to the first two sentences in my first comment.  Throw away what you have called a "read" function, since it does not read.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have updated the question with my new read function

Comment: "I am receiving 0 bytes".   According to what variable?  You aren't checking `dwRet` where the information actually is, and you aren't updating `receiveCharacterBytes` which you are checking.

Comment: @BenVoigt Do you mind if i can show you my function on my PC ? I can organize for a quick meet call if you dont mind just to show you the application running. I have updated the post with the latest read function.